# Java ADFS SSO migration

Tags: java, single-sign-on, adfs, onelogin

I to migrate my application to ADFS SSO.The flow is simple. Our application needs to get information from ADFS and send it to my server. I have no access to the ADFS. I have written a little application to test communication with ADFS, it uses OneLogin and it is deployed on Azure Ubuntu VM machine. But when I try to redirect to the ADFS server it says : "An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.". I guess it is because ADFS needs to know about my application. What information do I need to give to ADFS administration so that we can communicate? My app has no spring.

Answer (score 0):

What client side protocol stack are you using?

SAML, WS-Fed, ... ?

Do you have protocol metadata you can give the admin.?

What error is showing in the ADFS event log?

**Update**

You need a client side stack - [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) .

From the ADFS metadata, you need the signing certificate, the entityID and the SSO and SLO endpoints.

You add these to the config. options of whatever stack you choose.

Comment: ADFS ver 3.0, uses SAML protocol. I have just federationMetaData.xml from the ADFS server. I don't have access to the ADFS log. For now all I have is: ADFS server URL, federationMetadata.xml. Thats all. Where do i start. Can I communicate with server from localhost:8080 for example so i could test everything ?

Comment: Signing certificate is a long crypted string like this : "3HP264KgMyIOM7ShRom8RDRWy3hgABpeguiDwVXAQHeoRcyP27BVupHV3HP264KgMyIOM7ShRom8RDRWy3hgABpeguiDwVXAQHeoRcyP27BVupHV" ?, Entity Id is an URL of adfs server ?

Comment: It's in the ADFS metadata - entityID="http://your-adfs/adfs/services/trust"